# Character encoding issue with mySQL - '�'

Tags: php, mysql

The collation for the field is utf8_general_ci and the page's character set is utf8, but it appears that some of the data I am storing in my database is not being recognized. I keep getting this character � for something that appears to have no values in the field when looking at phpmyadmin.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's probably the back tick value " ` "

Comment: It may be a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Make sure that your connection is also set to utf8. `$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world;charset=utf8", 'my_user', 'my_pass');`, both in phpmyadmin and your code.

Comment: this can be solved by using ISO-8859-1 as the character set